# PHP Syntax Error On Apache 2.4.3 and PHP 5.4.7 (foreach template syntax)

Tags: php, apache, syntax, syntax-error

So I currently have a site running live in production on Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.3.18 and it functions as intended. I just set up a new development environment and decided to boot up Apache 2.4 and PHP 5.4.7 to try them out (Feature releases should not break anything I assumed).

Anyway, now the following code which executes fine on my production server is outputting the following error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach' (T_ENDFOREACH) in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\application\views\header_subnav.php on line 17
```

Is there something new I am missing, or is there a bad configuration or what?

Code:

```
<nav class="header_subnav">
                <div class="subnav_item_wrapper">
                    <a href="<?php echo URL::site(); ?>">Home</a>&nbsp;&#8594;&nbsp;
                </div>
                <?php $i = 0; ?>
                <?php foreach($subnav as $subnav_text => $subnav_uri): ?>
                        <?php if($i === count($subnav) - 1): ?>
                            <div class="subnav_item_wrapper">   
                                <?php echo $subnav_text; ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php break; ?>
                        <? endif; ?>
                        <div class="subnav_item_wrapper">
                            <a href="<?php echo URL::site($lang.'/'.$subnav_uri); ?>"><?php echo $subnav_text; ?></a><?php if($i !== count($subnav) - 1) echo '&nbsp;&#8594;&nbsp;'; ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php $i++; ?>
                <!-- LINE 17 -->
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </nav>
```

Comment: Well, this question/answer helped me immensely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short tag on your endif:

```
<? endif; ?>
```

should be

```
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Oh no. How embarrassing. sigh thanks

Comment: I hate XHTML for several reasons but forcing the creation of the [short_open_tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) directive is among my favourites.